# Expo XDE project has issues

Tags: ios, json, react-native, expo

I'm running an app in Expo XDE and get the following warning:

[Expo XDE warning screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLvDL.png)

The [link](https://docs.expo.io/) in the warning just takes you to the Expo docs. I looked through them and it looks like it might have something to do with my app.json file.

My app.json only contains:

```
{
 "expo": {
  "sdkVersion": "15.0.0"
 }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to get rid of this warning? I'm working in "development mode" (Expo IDE setting) on iOS/mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used **react-native** from **expo** like this in **package.json**:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/exponent/react-native/archive/sdk-16.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Comment: I had to change that link to be sdk-15 for my project but that worked. Thanks!